# SSH stops at "using username" with IPTables in effect

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, iptables, putty

We used UFW but couldn't make the Source Dedicated ports open, which was weird, so we purged UFW and switched to IPTables, using Webmin to configure.

If the inbound chain is on DENY and SSH port open [judged from Webmin], PuTTY will say `using username "root"` and stops at that instead of asking for public key pw. Inbound chain on ACCEPT the pw is asked. This problem didn't happen with UFW.

Picture of IPTables configuration in Webmin: http://s284544448.onlinehome.us/public/PlusLINE%20Dedicated%20Server,%20Webmin,%20IPTables,%200.jpg
The address is to the previous **rautamiekka.org**.

---

**EDIT 1:** I realized the system had Portsentry running but `aptitude remove` didn't help on this. I can't reboot yet.

---

**EDIT 2:** attempt on Ubuntu 11.10

```
administrator@rauta-m1530-ubuntu:~$ ssh -v -v -v -v -v -v -i ~/<filename removed> -l root <IP removed>
OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.0e 6 Sep 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <IP removed> [<IP removed>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/administrator/<filename removed>" as a RSA1 public key
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type 'Proc-Type:'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type 'DEK-Info:'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /home/administrator/<filename removed> type -1
debug1: identity file /home/administrator/<filename removed>-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "<IP removed>" from file "<filename removed>"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file <filename removed>:6
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: blowfish-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: blowfish-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client blowfish-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server blowfish-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 130/256
debug2: bits set: 521/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA f6:0a:d9:17:c1:ff:04:ec:f1:00:96:a7:61:20:5c:2e
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "<IP removed>" from file "<filename removed>"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file <filename removed>:6
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '<IP removed>' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in <filename removed>:6
debug2: bits set: 514/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/administrator/<filename removed> ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/administrator/<filename removed>
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphrase for key '/home/administrator/<filename removed>': 
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA 43:0d:b5:28:53:51:74:b8:3f:cb:0b:d0:9a:45:9e:6c
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to <IP removed> ([<IP removed>]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AGENT_PID
debug3: Ignored env GPG_AGENT_INFO
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_COOKIE
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWID
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL
debug3: Ignored env GTK_MODULES
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_PATH
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT_PATH
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
debug3: Ignored env USERNAME
debug3: Ignored env DEFAULTS_PATH
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
debug1: Sending env LC_MESSAGES = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_KEYRING_PID
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env MANDATORY_PATH
debug3: Ignored env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY
debug3: Ignored env GDMSESSION
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env LANGUAGE
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug3: Ignored env COLORTERM
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Last login: Fri Apr 13 13:46:17 2012 from 87-95-192-159.bb.dnainternet.fi
-bash-4.1# exitdebug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close

logout
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

Connection to <IP removed> closed.
Transferred: sent 3256, received 1888 bytes, in 22.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 147.1, received 85.3
debug1: Exit status 0
administrator@rauta-m1530-ubuntu:~$
```

By using the `plink.exe` shipped with installed PuTTY:

```
C:\Program Files\PuTTY>plink -v -v -v -ssh -l root -2 -i <filename removed> <IP removed>
Looking up host "<IP removed>"
Connecting to <IP removed> port 22
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.62
Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze1
Using SSH protocol version 2
Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
Host key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 f6:0a:d9:17:c1:ff:04:ec:f1:00:96:a7:61:20:5c:2e
Initialised Blowfish-128 CBC client->server encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm
Initialised Blowfish-128 CBC server->client encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm
Reading private key file "<filename removed>"
Using username "root".
Offered public key
Offer of public key accepted
Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key"
Passphrase for key "imported-openssh-key":
Sent public key signature
Access granted
Opened channel for session
Allocated pty (ospeed 38400bps, ispeed 38400bps)
Started a shell/command
Last login: Fri Apr 13 11:59:39 2012 from <address removed>
-bash-4.1# exitServer sent command exit status 0

logout
Disconnected: All channels closed

C:\Program Files\PuTTY>
```

---

**EDIT 4:** I dropped `LoginGraceTime` to 0 instead of 20 or so and the key pw is asked about 30 seconds after stating logging in as `root`, and login works. Minecraft takes a little longer to initially respond but works normally after that.

I think you want `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, so here it is:

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 4096

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel ERROR

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 0
PermitRootLogin without-password
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile <filename removed>

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding no
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM no

Ciphers blowfish-cbc
MaxAuthTries 2
GatewayPorts no
AllowTcpForwarding no
KeepAlive yes
AllowUsers root
```

---

`iptables-save` when on INPUT DENY:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.8 on Wed Apr 11 16:09:20 2012
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1430:156843]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1430:156843]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1415:781598]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1415:781598]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Apr 11 16:09:20 2012
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.8 on Wed Apr 11 16:09:20 2012
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2:104]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Apr 11 16:09:20 2012
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.8 on Wed Apr 11 16:09:20 2012
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1247:708906]
-A INPUT -i lo -m comment --comment "Machine-within traffic - always allowed" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m comment --comment "Services - TCP" -m tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443,10000,20,21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m comment --comment "Minecraft - TCP" -m tcp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m comment --comment "Minecraft - UDP" -m udp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m comment --comment "Source Dedicated - TCP" -m tcp --dport 27015 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m comment --comment "Source Dedicated - UDP" -m udp -m multiport --dports 4380,27000:27030 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m comment --comment "TS3 - UDP - main port" -m udp --dport 9987 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m comment --comment "TS3 - TCP - ServerQuery" -m tcp --dport 10011 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -m comment --comment "Machine-within traffic - always allowed" -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Apr 11 16:09:20 2012
```

`iptables --list` when on INPUT DENY:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            /* Machine-within traffic - always allowed */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            /* Services - TCP */ tcp multiport dports ssh,www,https,webmin,ftp-data,ftp state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            /* Minecraft - TCP */ tcp dpt:25565
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            /* Minecraft - UDP */ udp dpt:25565
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            /* Source Dedicated - TCP */ tcp dpt:27015
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            /* Source Dedicated - UDP */ udp multiport dports 4380,27000:27030
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            /* TS3 - UDP - main port */ udp dpt:9987
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            /* TS3 - TCP - ServerQuery */ tcp dpt:10011

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            /* Machine-within traffic - always allowed */
```

The UFW rules prior to purging on INPUT DENY:

```
127.0.0.1                  ALLOW IN    127.0.0.1
3306                       DENY IN     Anywhere
20,21/tcp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp (OpenSSH)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
989                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
990                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
8075/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
9987/udp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
10000/tcp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere
10011/tcp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere
25565/tcp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere
27000:27030/tcp            ALLOW IN    Anywhere
4380/udp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
27014:27050/tcp            ALLOW IN    Anywhere
30033/tcp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere
```

Comment: Is this an OpenVZ container?

Comment: @Vadym S. Khondar: no, nothing to do with that. A regular HP rack computer, all mine, no virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

The firewall rules look right. I'm not sure what that Putty output means in terms of the connection state -- can you provide `ssh -v` output from another client?

If it is establishing a connection but then hangs I would suspect MTU or MSS issues. Try decreasing the MTU on the server and client and checking if things work.

Are the other open protocols behaving normally from the same client machine you're testing from?

Comment: Yes, they do. Now that I tried, Minecraft crashes or something when using `/lb` on INPUT DENY. I'll update the OP when I get more issues, ok ?

Comment: [EDITED, Enter submitted ahead of time] PuTTY's process of connecting: 1st, try to find the host; 2nd, try to reach the Server software; 3rd, ask for username; 4th, ask for pw if demanded by Server software; 5th, ask for public key pw if embedded into file; 6th, send the username & pw to the Server software. In this problem whatever needed right before asking for key's pw doesn't arrive, leaving stuck at #3.